# How can I restore the display of the battery status on the lockscreen?

Tags: lock-screens, charging, samsung-galaxy-fit

I have a Samsung Galaxy Fit - GT S5670 model. When I charge the battery, there used be a percentage on the pattern screen. Somehow it is not showing now. All it is showing the word "Charging" but no numbers. Any ideas how can I get back the percentage status?

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that when I connect my phone with high voltage socket for charging it always shows charging percentage, but when I use a low voltage socket(using extension box, spike or similar things) it shows only "charging".

Answer (score 0):

Open the Phone app. Tap the number `*#*#4636#*#*` Before you can hit Dial, a screen with some info will pop up, including an option for Battery Info. Tap that and it will list.

source: Droid Incredible

Comment: That doesn't cause the percentage to be shown on the lock screen ...

Comment: @Kevin : it doesn't seem to be working. I tried tapping ##4636## on the phone, but nothing happens.

Comment: @MatthewRead : do you have any suggestions for me to try?

Comment: @Kaustubh The only thing I can think of is changing the unlock screen in `Settings -> Display`, but I don't know if that will help.

Comment: i don't know how, but somehow it started displaying the percentage as of now. so, for time being, the issue seems to be resolved. :)